# Spark check fails

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to set up my interpreter but I'm lost and I need some help. I set up my environmental variables (I think) but when I try to check the spark version using

> $spark  sc.version

I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:170)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
>       at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
>       at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
>       at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
>       at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I this saying that my `Java` is wrong? I have my environment variable for java home set like so:

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java8

So I would expect the interpreter to use java8 and work.

Any help is appreciated!